# https://subdomain.example.com redirect to https://example.com:port

Tags: mod-rewrite, ssl, https

Recently purchased a SSL certificate for our main domain and www.domain.  Not a wildcard certificate.

I have rewrite rule that redirects all http://subdomain.example.com -> https://example.com:port

However, when I directly type https:/subdomain.example.com it brings up the Untrusted Connection message.  Is there any way to make it so it doesn't do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect all www (http or https) to https://domain.com  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com:80/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect http://domain.com to https://domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [nc]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com:80/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect all sub domain (http or https) to https://domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\-]+)\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^www$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com:80/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm starting to find out that this may not be possible due to the SSL being verified before the rewrite rules are used.  I may be wrong on this, but either way I can deal with it, it was more of a convenience than a necessity.  Thanks.